# auto generate html for uploading images

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website coded in html/css, php and js (the latter two parts are just a few basic functions).

When I want to upload an image, I hardcode it. It's a decent solution but now I have to upload 300'ish images (it's for customers who wants to view their images - I'm a photographer).

That will take hours to type so is there a way that I can upload 300 images at once where it autogenerates the following code (however, the .jpg-filename should follow its own filename, and both the "id" and "ng-show" must be incremented each time). It must follow the following format:

```
<li  class="span4 gallery-item" data-id="id-1">

             <img class="fancybox" src="img/photoshop2_small.jpg" data-big="img/photoshop2.jpg" ng-click="showFacebook = 1;" />

              <div ng-show="showFacebook === 1"
              class="fb-like"  data-href="img/photoshop2.jpg" data-width="300"

             data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true" >
      </div>

</li>
```

I feel this is not possible and the only solutions I've found is where it auto generates a simple html code, but this is not useful in my case.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either Upload all the images using 1) FTP or 2) use some php file manager
2. use php directory functions to retrieve the files in an array
3. Loop through the array and echo your html
4. use the filename from array value for .jpg-filename, increment a variable in each loop and use for the "id" and "ng-show"

Comment: I think this solution seems reasonable.  

I've passed step one, now I just need to figure out how to do the rest. I'm a newbie, so it might be tough.

Comment: Hi again. 

I'm very sorry if it's against the rules (I'm a bit rusty) and/or if i put you in a position you dislike, so with that being said, here's my question for you: Can you develop this for me? I will pay of course. I'm a bit ... well, noob'ish at this.

Comment: No worries. I can help you. have you uploaded all the images?

Comment: Yes I have. I have an folder named "img" with all the photos :)

Comment: Lovely. Sent you an email :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular, why not implement a service to get a list of the images and do something like;

```
<li  class="span4 gallery-item" ng-repeat="image in images track by $index" data-id="id-{{image.ID}}">
    <img class="fancybox" src="{{image.smallURL}}" data-big="{{image.bigURL}}" ng-click="showFacebook = image.ID;" />
    <div ng-show="showFacebook === 1" class="fb-like" data-href="{{image.bigURL}}" data-width="{{image.width}}" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
</li>
```

Another option is to do this in PHP, which is probably better.

Comment: Seems like an acceptable solution but I think it's too tricky for me.

Comment: I figured you might be familiar with Angular, since you're using it, but PHP will be the easiest solution :)